# Building freetype2 in a custom directory which must be found when building GD

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, gd, freetype2

On my Ubuntu 16.04 I'm trying to build `freetype-2.8` and `libgd-2.2.4`.

Here is how I build freetype2:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-bzip2
make
make install
make clean
```

Here is how I build libgd:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-jpeg=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-png=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-freetype=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-zlib=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-xpm
```

The `configure` command reports it finds `freetype2`:

```
 Support for Freetype 2.x library: yes
```

But the make fails with the error:

```
gdft.c:154:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
```

I can see `freetype2` was installed in the following directories:

```
$ ll /home/stephane/programs/install/lib/libfreetype.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 6752986 août  11 06:39 /home/stephane/programs/install/lib/libfreetype.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane stephane    1068 août  11 06:39 /home/stephane/programs/install/lib/libfreetype.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane      21 août  11 06:39 /home/stephane/programs/install/lib/libfreetype.so -> libfreetype.so.6.14.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane      21 août  11 06:39 /home/stephane/programs/install/lib/libfreetype.so.6 -> libfreetype.so.6.14.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 stephane stephane 3219752 août  11 06:39 /home/stephane/programs/install/lib/libfreetype.so.6.14.0*

$ ll /home/stephane/programs/install/include/freetype2/
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 stephane stephane 4096 août  11 06:39 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 stephane stephane 4096 août  11 06:59 ../
drwxrwxr-x 3 stephane stephane 4096 août  11 06:39 freetype/
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 2383 août  11 06:39 ft2build.h
```

And there are no `freetype2` header files in the `/home/stephane/programs/install/include/` directory:

```
$ ll /home/stephane/programs/install/include/
total 252
drwxrwxr-x 4 stephane stephane  4096 août  11 06:59 ./
drwxrwxr-x 9 stephane stephane  4096 août  10 23:20 ../
drwxrwxr-x 3 stephane stephane  4096 août  11 06:39 freetype2/
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane  1757 août  11 00:24 jconfig.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 14580 août  11 00:24 jerror.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 14925 août  11 00:24 jmorecfg.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 49287 août  11 00:24 jpeglib.h
drwxrwxr-x 2 stephane stephane  4096 août  11 05:59 libpng16/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane    18 août  11 05:59 pngconf.h -> libpng16/pngconf.h
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane    14 août  11 05:59 png.h -> libpng16/png.h
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane    21 août  11 05:59 pnglibconf.h -> libpng16/pnglibconf.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 35028 août  11 06:49 t1tables.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 16262 août   5 14:37 zconf.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 96239 août   5 14:37 zlib.h
```

How to have `freetype2` install its header files in the expected `include` directory ?

Note: I know I could install a package using `sudo apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev` but this is not what I want. I want to build it myself.

I upgraded the release of GD to `libgd-2.2.5` but the exact same error keeps occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `2.7.1` version of `freetype` I can build GD just fine.

There is something that changed in `freetype` from `freetype-2.7.1` to `freetype-2.8.*` that breaks the build of `libgd-2.2.4` or `libgd-2.2.5`.